# QField: Searchbar

Tags: qfield

I have a QField project with different vectorlayers and what to use the search bar from QField. Only I don't really know how to use the search bar, even if it sounds stupid.

According to the documentation you need at least 3 characters to trigger a search. In one layer I have the column "nk" with an 8 digit unique number for each object. I want to use the search function to quickly display the desired objects. If I enter an object number, after entering the first 3 digits, I get a selection of objects from another layer that also happen to have this sequence of numbers in a column. After I have entered the object number completely, QField does not find anything anymore.

Do I have to prepare the data specifically in QGIS before importing it into QField? With a classic QGIS query: "nk" = '43491230' I unfortunately don't reach the goal either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two Steps to enhance your search for Qfield:

1. In your QGIS Project go to Project-> Properties -> Data Sources. Remove the ticks from layers which should not be searchable.
   [image]
2. Go into the Layer Properties of the layer which should be searchable. Go to "Display" - here you can chose the field, which should be searchable - you can also set an expression to combine several fields. Note: the display expression is also used to show the "name" of a feature when selecting features on the map canvas.

[image]